# How to Clear WebGL Render Queue?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, render

I am currently developing an application that constantly draws video to WebGL in a canvas element. A requirement of the application is that the canvas gets hidden with `display: none;` immediately after frames stop being send to render. The canvas will be brought back into view with `display: block;` if and when we decide to send more frames to the renderer.

My issue is that at the time the canvas is hidden, WebGL doesn't seem to have finished rendering the older frames, resulting in seeing old frames catching up when the canvas reappears.

My only viable find so far was to use `gl.clear` as shown below.

```
var gl = this.contextGL;
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

While this does clear the frame, it still only does this after drawing the old frames, followed by the new frames.

Is there a way to clear out the old frames that are queued up? If not, is there a way to force webGL to render while out of view?